# terminate infinite loop initiated in remote server when exiting bash script

Tags: linux, bash

Script which executes commands in infinite loop in background

```
<SOMETHING ELSE AT START OF SCRIPT>

cmd='while true;
do
    ps aux | head;
    sleep 1;
done > $FILE'    

ssh root@$SERVER $cmd &
...
...
<SOME OTHER TASKS>
...
...
( at the end of this script, how to kill the above snippet executing in remote server)
[ kindly note i dont want to wait as the while loop is infinite ]
```

Read and tried some posts from stackoverflow, but could not find exact solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than an infinite loop, use a sentinel file:

```
cmd='while [ -r /tmp/somefile];
do
  # stuff
done > $FILE'

ssh root@$SERVER touch /tmp/somefile
ssh root@$SERVER $cmd &
# do other stuff
ssh root@$SERVER rm -f /tmp/somefile
```

This follows your current practice of putting the remote command in a variable, but the arguments against that cited elsewhere should be considered.

Comment: better way to achieve that..! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to kill the ssh process running in background at the end of your script, just do:

```
kill $!
```

I assume this is the only (or the last) process you started in background.

Comment: Or something like `rpid=$(ssh remote 'commands & echo $!'); : ... Other stuff ...; ssh remote "kill $rpid"`. I would avoid putting the remote commands in a variable for the regular reasons; http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Comment: Even though it kills ssh command when doing kill $!, it does not kill the process in remote server. There the while loop continues to run !

Comment: No. When you do 'ssh root@$SERVER $cmd &' you don't start a background process on the remote server, but you actually put your local ssh client into background. So to stop the remote process your ssh client is controlling on the remote server you need to kill your local ssh client process, and that is running in background cause you used ampersand when you run it.

Comment: Yes, that is the same i exactly meant. The process 'ssh' running in background because of ampersand, and it gets killed with 'kill $!'. But am really wondering how that particular snippet of code continues to run in the remote server even after the ssh which initiated this has terminated. Simple - if you do try this you will also face the same I believe ! ... Anyway i used the sentinel file concept which seemed more robust to me.. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try following sequence

```
CTRL+Z
fg
CTRL+C
```

or

```
jobs
kill %jobspec
```

Answer (score 0):

To kill everything belonging to user logged in you could try:

```
 whois=`w|grep $user|awk '{print $2}'`;user=root; ssh $user@server -C "ps auwx|grep $whois|awk '{print \$2}'"
```

This will list all the processes owned by the user you just logged in as - just add |xargs kill -9

```
 whois=`w|grep $user|awk '{print $2}'`;user=root; ssh $user@server -C "ps auwx|grep $whois|awk '{print \$2}'|xargs kill -9  "


 whois=`w|grep $user|awk '{print $2}'`;user=root; ssh $user@server -C "ps auwx|grep $whois|awk '{print \$2}'|awk '{print "kill -9 " $1}'|/bin/sh "
```